# Problems with Android Gameloop (openGL ES 2.0)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, game-loop

**Overview**

Having a lot of problem with choppy animations in my game loop.  I'm running the loop from 
**onDrawFrame** and as you can see, my loop allows for frame skipping if it takes too long (I'm using a fixed time delta and my time 'slice' for 60fps is 16.666666ms).

I've confirmed that the stuttering happens when frames are skipped.

- When there are frame skips, how can I stop the animation from going choppy?

If it absolutely has to skip frames (I concede there will be times on certain devices when this will happen), how can I mitigate the choppiness?

- onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) seems to be called up to 24ms since the last time it was called.

On my Google Nexus 10 Tablet, my actual **rendering** can take anywhere between 5 and 14ms and my **game updates** only take between 0 and 4ms so most of the time it should fit nicely into the 16.6666 time slice.  However, when I remove everything from onDrawFrame, it seems to be called anywhere from 16 to 25ms apart.  (Most times, it is above 16ms), therefore, it's skipping a lot of frames - even without rendering or updates being called!!

This seems to go against the whole point of a device running at 60FPS - is this VSync doing this?  What's the point of it taking more than 16ms?

**Things I've attempted**

OK, I tried spawning a separate thread on which I run my updates (again, limiting them to 60 per second).  I still get the problem.

I've also tried interpolation but this again, hasn't made any difference.  (I am going to be posting a separate question to see if I've got that right).

I'm really struggling with this so I hope someone can help!

**Code**

```
float interpolation;
long nextGameTick = System.currentTimeMillis();
//loop counter
int loops;
//This is the amount of frames that we allow our app to skip before logic updating is affected (generally shouldn't happen)
final int maxFrameskip = 5;                             
//Game updates per second
final int ticksPerSecond = 60;
//Amount of time each update should take        
final int skipTicks = (1000 / ticksPerSecond);

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {


        //Set/Re-set loop back to 0 to start counting again
        loops=0;

        while(System.currentTimeMillis() > nextGameTick && loops < maxFrameskip){

        SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().updateLogic();
        nextGameTick+=skipTicks;
        timeCorrection += (1000d/ticksPerSecond) % 1;
        nextGameTick+=timeCorrection;
        timeCorrection %=1;
        loops++;
        tics++;

     }

        interpolation = (float)(System.currentTimeMillis() + skipTicks - nextGameTick)
              / (float)skipTicks; 

    render(interpolation);
}
```

**Applying interpolation**

```
render(float interpolation){

    //This example shows interpolation for X axis only.  Y position (spriteScreenY is assumed to be valid)
    interpolatedPosX = spriteGridX+(SpriteXVelocity*dt)*interpolation;
    spriteScreenPosX = interpolationPosX * screenWidth;

    drawSprite(spriteScreenX, spriteScreenY);           


}
```

Comment: Do you allocate any memory in your game loop (remember that iterating through collections with for-each syntax allocates a an iterator)? GC may cause stuttering. Check logcat debug messages for "D/dalvikvm GC_CONCURRENT freed", it will show you how long it paused.

Comment: Hi @thanks for the comment - there is no allocation happening during my loop - this is one of the first things I checked so I ruled that out early on - cheers!

Comment: @Zippy Do you solve the isssue.I have the same problem

Comment: Hi @Sunny, unfortunately, I haven't solved it. I've tried everything but still have choppy animation when frames are skipped.  For now, I'm just living with it but need to re-visit it at some point.  If you come across any suggestions, would love to hear them!! :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try using RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY. This means not using onDrawFrame anymore, but instead using requestRender() in your game loop.